# stop thread that does not get interrupted

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, objectinputstream

I have a thread that sits and reads objects off of an ObjectInputStream:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        Object o;
        while ((o = ois.readObject()) != null) {
            //do something with object
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Log exception
    }
}
```

readObject does not throw InterruptedException and as far as I can tell, no exception is thrown when this thread is interrupted. How do I stop this thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `close` on the socket input stream. You should be able to do that from another thread.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `clientSocket` is your only externally visible reference.  From another thread, call `clientSocket.close()`

That will force the `ObjectInputStream` to [throw the IOException on the readObject()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject()) call.  That should trigger your catch block and get you out of the loop.

Re-reading your question, you say that `readObject` doesn't throw InterruptedException.  You're correct in that point: I'm looking at the source for `readObject` right now and it neither `throws` nor does it explicitly hide the `InterruptedException`.

You should always be able to trigger that final `catch (Exception ex)` block (AKA exception eater) by calling `objectReadingThread.interrupt()` from another thread (or whatever you name your reading thread).  Quoting the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29):

> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long),
>   or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(),
>   join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int), methods
>   of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will
>   receive an InterruptedException.
>
> If this thread is blocked in an I/O operation upon an interruptible
>   channel then the channel will be closed, the thread's interrupt status
>   will be set, and the thread will receive a ClosedByInterruptException.
>
> If this thread is blocked in a Selector then the thread's interrupt
>   status will be set and it will return immediately from the selection
>   operation, possibly with a non-zero value, just as if the selector's
>   wakeup method were invoked.
>
> If none of the previous conditions hold then this thread's interrupt
>   status will be set.

If that isn't working, I would investigate that "do something with object" block and try to find the exception-eater that is consuming your interrupt and ignoring it.

Comment: Comment from a <50 user: "InterruptedException does not require you to have a throws clause in the method declaration." It is not true. The InterruptedException is not a RuntimeException, so it must be declared explicitly.

Comment: @assylias, you're right, the sentence as originally written wasn't making my point that readObject is not the only place where interrupted would have an effect.  I removed that sentence and added the javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to catch [InterruptedIOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InterruptedIOException.html) . I don't know if in your particular case it helps but it is a most clear Java way to deal with such cases.

I am dealing with a amazing case when despite catching of IOException in some magic way EOFException is uncaught, so I found your answer interesting as well. In another case there is a InterruptException despite it could not be : [link to unexpected InterruptException](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t131304-interruptedexception-and-i-o.html). These cases have in common problems with exceptions handling close to I/O operations.